# GNOME Check night light state

Tags: command-line, gnome, settings, console

Referring to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400025/activate-night-light-option-from-terminal) I managed to turn night light on/off via console. I wonder if theres any option to check the state of the night light. I tried this:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled = true`

I also tried to use echo to see what that line returns. Like so:

`echo gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled`

But I'm not doing this right either. Anyway I'm new to Linux. I'd appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: Try the command without the `=` in it.

Comment: @Terrance Tried, it only changes the state to true. Doesn't give any return values

Comment: To get the return value it is `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled` .  The `set` will not return any values.